# Unit Tests for C# in Visual Studio - Assert.AreEqual

Tags: visual-studio-2008, assert

I have a class for which I have overridden the .Equals(), ==, !=, + and % Operators. Clearly, I want to test if everything works fine. What's pretty funny is, that the test for the addition '+' is successful inside a program, but fails, when using a real UnitTest!

In Program:

```
        Stats a = new Stats();
        Stats b = new Stats();
        Stats expected = new Stats();
        Stats actual = new Stats();

        a.AC = 5;
        b.AC = 10;
        expected.AC = 15;

        actual = a + b;
        bool r1 = (expected == actual);     //true
        bool r2 = expected.Equals(actual);  //true
```

In UnitTest:

```
        Stats a = new Stats();
        Stats b = new Stats(); 
        Stats expected = new Stats();
        Stats actual = new Stats();

        a.AC = 5;
        b.AC = 10;
        expected.AC = 15;

        actual = a + b;
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

Test Fails.

It seems I am not getting something here... Who can help?

Best regards,
Christian

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(VS.80).aspx

Comment: If you debug the running unit test, is value of the field correct? And have you stepped in AreaEqual to see what it ends up calling.

Comment: Hmm, it seems the debugger just ignores my breakpoints in my Testclass...

Comment: Also, I read the Equals() guidelines. The Equals() method actually works. The expected.Equals(actual) returns true in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that any class that overrides Equals also override `System.Object.GetHashCode`. [Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return AC;
        }

Comment: public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return AC;
}

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Debugging (CTRL+R, CTRL+T) showed me, that the UnitTest used an older version of my class. After wildly rebuilding, it used the actual version for testing.

That's quite annoying, but I am sure I will find a way to assure that the Unit Test do only test the most actual version of each class.

Thank you guys!